# i'm trying to run gulp command but its saying "Elixir.ready is not a function"

Tags: laravel, gulp, vagrant, homestead, laravel-elixir

I'm running vagrant Homestead on ubuntu 16 and gulp 3.9.1, when i try to run gulp it sends me an error below

```
vagrant@homestead:~/practice$ gulp
/home/vagrant/practice/node_modules/laravel-elixir-vue-2/index.js:3
Elixir.ready(function () {
       ^

TypeError: Elixir.ready is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/practice/node_modules/laravel-elixir-vue-2/index.js:3:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/practice/gulpfile.js:3:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
```

any help about this will be highly encouraged.

Comment: if anybody want more information about the environment i'm working on let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try updating you elixir to the latest version in the `package.json` file, and if you're using it with webpack then also install the webpack package in `package.json` file or do it by running the below command in terminal.

```
npm install laravel-elixir-webpack-official --save-dev
```

For more help see - [this issue](https://github.com/JeffreyWay/Laravel-Elixir-v6-Vue-example/issues/1)

Comment: @SulemanAkram If it worked for you them accept & upvote this answer, which makes me motivated against answering more questions like this... :D